# Jackson and Lombok: MismatchedInputException when Attributes are Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, lombok

I have a Job class looking like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Job implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String job;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("jobs")
    private Job next;
```

and a method to create jobs:

```
    @PostMapping("/jobs")
    public ResponseEntity<Job> createJob(@Valid @RequestBody Job job) throws URISyntaxException {
        Job result = jobRepository.save(job);
        return ...
    }
```

Everything works fine until here. Adding the @AllArgsConstructor to the Job class now leads to an MismatchedInputException.

```
Bad Request: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.domain.Job` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.domain.Job` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I tried to add `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true` to lombok.config file, as described in may answers I found. But this leads only to following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project-name ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 27 source files to /path/target/test-classes
Unknown key 'lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties' (/path/lombok.config:2)
```

I tried to use an older version of lombok, as I found some github issues addressing this problem on updating lombok. Also, no success (tried version 1.16.18)

I tried also to remove the `private Job next` attribute which made the code work without any errors. So this must somehow be a problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this github issue: https://github.com/meltmedia/jackson-crypto/issues/6

as described there, i fixed the problem by setting:

```
jackson:
    mapper:
        INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES: false
```

[Jackson Doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES) says:

> **Feature is mostly used to help interoperability with frameworks like Lombok** that may automatically
>   generate ConstructorProperties annotation but without necessarily
>   meaning that constructor should be used as Creator for
>   deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

You probably don't want `@ConstructorProperties` in any form.

The key `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true` is no longer available, for unfortunate reasons. The right key is `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = false`, though you probably don't want to actually apply this configuration key.

The fix is probably to update your build tooling to tell javac to generate parameter name info in the class files.

### You don't want @ConstructorProperties

The 'point' of the `@ConstructorProperties` annotation is two-fold: To allow runtime code (java code, using reflection APIs) to check the *names* of the parameters of a constructor, and to allow compile-time tooling to figure out the *names* of the parameters of a constructor if all that is available is a compiled (class) file, and not source (java) files.

For that purpose, however, `@ConstructorProperties` is obsolete. These days, most compiler configurations have been updated to default to including parameter names in class files, and the reflection APIs have been updated to give you an easy way to get at these. For example:

```
public class Example {
    public Example(String a, int b) {}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Example.class
            .getConstructor(String.class, int.class)
            .getParameters()[1]
            .getName());
    }
}
```

then on the command line:

```
javac Example.java
java Example
arg1

javac -parameters Example.java
java Example
b
```

You may want to include the above source file in your build as a quick check to ensure that the `-parameters` option is being set by whatever build system you're using to build your source files. It should print `b`, and if it does not (if it prints `arg1`), do a quick search on how to make maven or gradle or whatever's relevant emit parameter name info during its compilations.

Now jackson has a chance to just use this information (instead of relying on `@ConstructorProperties`). I don't actually know if it does, but I would assume so: This is the 'new' way to do it.

### Why you don't want it

... because the java community cannot be trusted with it, as proven by history.

The annotation started out being a simple, clear design (you use it to pass the names of the parameters in annotation form), and almost immediately, the community at large messed up: Both android and GWT would refuse to compile your code if this annotation was even in your java files.

Then, for a while, all was well, and all most recent versions of everything that can feasibly compile code in files ending with the `.java` extension would all at the very least silently ignore this annotation.

But then java9 with the module system came out, and in oracle's infinite wisdom, they decided to.... shove this annotation into... the... `java.desktop` module??? To this day I have absolutely no idea what happened there, as that seems like a *wildly* inappropriate module for it. But, it does mean that if you want to use `ConstructorProperties` in any form on modularized builds (i.e. anything with a `module-info.java` file in the root), you need to add `requires java.desktop;` to it, except that tends to imply things that make no sense (Such as: That your module cannot run on headless JVMs).

This gets at the two points: [1] why the lombok configuration and behaviour for constructorproperties is so messed up, and [2] why I advise you not to use `@ConstructorProperties`.

### Lombok's configuration

If regardless of the above advice you really do want to use `ConstructorProperties`, the right configuration in lombok is:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = false
```

The config keys in lombok for generating `@ConstructorProperties` has gone on a bit of an unfortunate wild ride due to the above history. I do apologize for the hardship this has caused you. (I am a core lombok contributor).

Originally, `addConstructorProperties` existed (vs. the much simpler: always generate this annotation, and having no configuration key at all) because android and GWT couldn't handle its presence, and in our estimation, more people used android/GWT+lombok, than people who relied upon `@ConstructorProperties` being generated, thus we decided that the appropriate default behaviour should be to not include the annotation when generating a constructor.

Then when GWT/Android fixed the problem, the balance of power shifted: We now realized that 'generate it by default' was more likely to help than hurt. We really, really wanted our properties to always 'default to false', thus, we renamed the key to `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties` instead.

Then in an even later version of lombok, after abandoning the 'we wish all things to default to false' maxim, we changed the default behaviour back to what it was: Do *NOT* generate `ConstructorProperties` by default. This was right at the point when doing so would result in code that didn't compile at all if you're using a modularized build, due to the annotation being placed in the `java.desktop` module. Whilst the java community at large continues to largely avoid jigsaw, a few do use it, more than enough to shift the balance of power back. In addition it is clear to us now that `@ConstructorProperties` as a mechanism is doomed, with the `-parameters` switch the right, less headaches solution.

We expect the behaviour of lombok not to change a third time.

Comment: I always thought it was the other way around, that `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties` was the new config key, or at least the one for recent versions.

Comment: Augh! Okay, it's just a mess... relevant commits are https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/commit/d7c019c07 from 2017 and https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/commit/d41ef4bf8 from 2014. - but yes, addConstructorProperties does postdate it. I'd swear addCP was the older one...

Comment: I added the -parameters option and it is printing the name of the parameter correctly but the MismatchedInputException is still thrown.

Comment: Oof, then I'm at a loss, and someone with more knowledge on Jackson would have to chime in to help you out :(